# Taylor series error?

Tags: gamma-function, uniform-continuity

I was playing around with Taylor series and a shifted Gamma Function and found something that doesn't work, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Is it some uniform continuity problem?

Let:
$$\Pi(n)=\int_0^\infty t^ne^{-t}dt$$

For non negative integers $n$, this is $n!$.

Suppose we have a Maclaurin Series for some $f(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kt^k$ where $c_k=\frac{1}{k!}\frac{d^kf(t)}{dt^k}|_{t=0}$

Then I'd expect:

$$\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-t}dt=\int_0^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kt^ke^{-t}dt=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty c_kt^ke^{-t}dt=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kk!=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{d^kf}{dt^k}\bigg|_{t=0}$$

Now suppose $f(t)=\sin(t)$. Then the derivatives cycle through 0,1,-1,0, and so on.

The sum doesn't converge, yet the integral is 1/2.

What's going on? Is there a function other than a finite sum of polynomials for which this works?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation

Comment: The root of the problem lies with uniform convergence of the partial sums of the sine function on $\Bbb R$. That is, if you define a sequence of functions to be the partial sums of the sine function, then the sum converges pointwise to $\sin(x)$ but not uniformly, which means you can't reverse the order of integration/limits.